# How to get the beginning of date an end of date with the date function

Tags: sql

I have this statement in the where clause.

```
Where e.id=t.event_id 
  AND deceased='N'  
  AND birth_datetime BETWEEN Cast('1/1/2001'AS Datetime) AND Cast('12/31/2013' AS datetime)
```

But, I want to get the end of the date. I need to know how to get the end of each date?

Comment: What do you mean by 'end of each date'?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a Less than clause for the day after.  Everything BEFORE 1/1/2014 is ALL of 12/31/2013.

```
Where e.id=t.event_id 
  AND deceased='N'  
  AND birth_datetime >= Cast('1/1/2001'AS Datetime) 
  AND birth_datetime <  Cast('1/1/2014' AS datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just add the time to the string:

```
Where e.id=t.event_id 
  AND deceased='N'  
  AND birth_datetime BETWEEN '1/1/2001' AND '12/31/2013 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to include all hours, you could just look at the DATE portion for both sides:

```
Where e.id=t.event_id 
  AND deceased='N'  
  AND CAST(birth_datetime AS DATE) BETWEEN Cast('1/1/2001'AS DATE) AND Cast('12/31/2013' AS DATE)
```